# Use p12 file permanently in JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, p12

`P12` certificate file is needed to execute testcase. I set it in `JMeter` in `Options -> SSL Manager`. It asks for password when testcase is executed, but it is working just until JMeter is restarted. After that I have to provide it again in SSL Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Add the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/certificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=certificate_password
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

Alternatively you can pass the aforementioned properties to JMeter startup script via -D command-line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=certificate_password
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: I set it and execute `jmeter.bat`, but seemly it isn't uses these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Set in system.properties:

> javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password of file
>
> javax.net.ssl.keyStore=path to file

Comment: I set it and execute jmeter.bat, but seemly it isn't uses these parameters.

Comment: `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\ssl\mycertificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass`